# Correct way to omit dot in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, luatex, biber

I tried to improve my latex-code and wanted to make sure that if there is an edition, it would not be preceded by a dot as I set it up to be in brackets (and having a dot in front + after a bracket looks odd to me).

This was my old code:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  datamodel=customstyles,
  maxnames=25,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  usetranslator=true,
  alldates=terse,
  labeldate=year,
  dashed=false,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
% edition in front of addendum in parantheses
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{edition}{}
\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
    {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit}
\usepackage[hidelinks, pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{microtype}% avoid bib formatting issues
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Wittgenstein.1999,
    address = {Cambridge, Mass.},
    author = {Wittgenstein, Ludwig},
    date-modified = {2021-04-20 20:44:48 +0900},
    edition = {Nachdruck der 2. Aufl., Erstauflage 1953},
    isbn = {0-631-14670-9},
    publisher = {Blackwell},
    title = {Philosophische Untersuchungen. Philosophical Investigations},
    translator = {Anscombe, G. E. M.},
    year = {1999}}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\cite{Wittgenstein.1999}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is how I amended the code:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  datamodel=customstyles,
  maxnames=25,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  usetranslator=true,
  alldates=terse,
  labeldate=year,
  dashed=false,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
% edition in front of addendum in parantheses
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{edition}{}
\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
    {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
   \setunit{\space}%
   \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit}
\usepackage[hidelinks, pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{microtype}% avoid bib formatting issues
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Wittgenstein.1999,
    address = {Cambridge, Mass.},
    author = {Wittgenstein, Ludwig},
    date-modified = {2021-04-20 20:44:48 +0900},
    edition = {Nachdruck der 2. Aufl., Erstauflage 1953},
    isbn = {0-631-14670-9},
    publisher = {Blackwell},
    title = {Philosophische Untersuchungen. Philosophical Investigations},
    translator = {Anscombe, G. E. M.},
    year = {1999}}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\cite{Wittgenstein.1999}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Is this the correct way to do it or should I consider approaching it differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That - as in

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{edition}{}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
    {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\space}%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit}
```

is pretty much how I would do it as well.

I'd just use `\setunit{\addspace}%` instead of `\setunit{\space}`. `\addspace` is a `biblatex` command that does a little additional housekeeping compared to `\space`. (It tries to avoid unwanted double spaces etc. If the rest of the code is good, the housekeeping is probably not needed. But it is the usual `biblatex` idiom to go for `\addspace` here instead of `\space`.)

Specifically `\setunit{\addspace}` (or `\setunit{\space}`) adds a space to `biblatex`'s punctuation buffer that is then going to be printed before the `edition` if the field is non-empty. If the `edition` field is empty, the space remains in the buffer until the next printable thing is encountered. But that will usually be preceded by another `\setunit` that overwrites the space in the buffer.

For all intents and purposes `\newunit` is equivalent to `\setunit{\newunitpunct}` and would thus have done the same except with `\newunitpunct` (by default a period plus a space) instead of a space.

Bottom line: If you want to control the punctuation *before* a particular field, just use `\setunit` before the relevant `\printfield`.